# How to disable current date by time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time, disabled-input

I have used input date type in my website. I want to disable current date by time.

**For example**

After `12:00:00 PM` current date `2018-04-16` disabled.

I tried this code:

```js
<!-- disable past date -->
$(function() {
  var dtToday = new Date();

  var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dtToday.getDate();
  var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();

  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  //console.log(maxDate);
  $('#demo_date').attr('min', maxDate);
  $('#demo_date').attr('max', '2018-04-29');
});
<!-- disable past date -->

<!-- disable date by time -->
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  if (time <= '12:00:00 PM') {

    // code for disable demo_date
  }
});

<!-- disable date by time -->
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Select Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" name="demo_date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="demo_date">
```

Comment: what's the issue ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey: I want to disable todate by time. I mean after `12:00:00 PM` todate can disable

Comment: you want to disable current date alone? or all previous date too?

Comment: current date alone

Comment: current date alone cant be disabled. but you can show ERROR message on selecting current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you got it. I have made a demo for you here you will not able to select the current date after 12:00 pm. Cheers....

```js
$(function() {
  var dtToday = new Date();

  var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dtToday.getDate();
  var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
 
 
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();

  var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  //console.log(maxDate);
 
   var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  if (time >= '12:00:00 PM') {
 day = day+1
 maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    // code for disable demo_date
  }
 
  
  
  $('#demo_date').attr('min', maxDate);
  $('#demo_date').attr('max', '2018-04-29');
});
<!-- disable past date -->

<!-- disable date by time -->
$(document).ready(function() {
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Select Date" class="textbox-n" type="text" name="demo_date" onfocus="(this.type='date')" id="demo_date">
```

Comment: its the beauty we have many diffrent formats of date. can use them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

By the below result in browser console:

```
>> var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
undefined
>> time
"11:27:28 AM"
>> time <= '12:00:00 PM'
true
```

code works fine.But you should define the other part of expression. you should define :

```
if( time >= some_date_value && time <= some_date_value ) 
{
    // code for disable demo_date
}
```

Comment: Hissein: Thanks for your code. I can't understand in my browser console   var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); shows current time

Comment: For Ex, in chrome browser, u can use developer tools console to run JavaScript code onthefly. its not matter;) Just use as reference to mentioned code.